# Let some types of users to edit content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I managed to check controller for authenticate user by:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit]
```

How can I let only users with rights 'administrator' and 'editor' edit and create the content?

I want somethng like:

```
before_filter :current_user.rights == 'editor', only: [:new, :edit]
```

to check current logged in user for value in db's column "rights"

btw I'm using devise and only 1 registration form for users. There is a checkbox for users 'rights' (because 'type' isn't allowed and i don't want to change that).

[image: Regitration form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `before_filter`

```
before_filter :authorize_admin, :only => [...]

def authorize_admin
  unless currenct_user.admin? # Add your logic here
    redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'You are not authorized') and return
  end
end
```

If there are multiple user roles and permissions, you could try [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Comment: And can I use something like current_user.right == "editor" ??? I need this type of logic, but such input doesn't work

Comment: I completely advise against the `cancan` gem. That gem is no longer being maintained and it has 230 (!) issues on GitHub. A better alternative would be [the pundit gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

Answer (score 1):

Use cancan gem here you can find nice documentation https://github.com/ryanb/cancan
just one line will do it for you after defining Abilities for users

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

Optionally you can pass method as parameters with only and except